# How to find equation of a tangent

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

How to find equation of a tangent on a $4x^2+9y^2-24x+18y+9=0$ in $T(6,-1)$?

The solution is $x=6$, but I always get: $y = \frac{-4}{15}x + \frac {3}{5} $(?!)

Alternate form:

[image]

This is the ellipse we get: (if that helps)

[image]

Comment: I don't know why I keep getting such weird equation of a tangent... I can be seen (even) from the picture that equation of a tangent in T(6,-1) is x=6, but how to get to that solution?

Comment: It's a point which lies on this ellipse.

Comment: It is an ellipse with center (3,-1) with a = 3 an b = 2 From the center to the right end is (6,-1) and the only line that could be the tangent is x=6.  You don't need to solve algebraic methods, if you do it well and good but it is clear that x=6 is the only solution.

Comment: Yes, I know it's logical, but I need to write down the procedure of solving this ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $4x^2+9y^2-24x+18y+9=0$ is:

$$8x+18yy'-24+18y'=0$$

or

$$4x+9yy'-12+9y'=0$$

Then,

$$ 9yy'+9y'=12-4x $$

$$9y'(y+1)=12-4x$$

Therefore, $y'=\frac{12-4x}{9(y+1)}$

Now, substitute $x=6, \ y=-1$  to find $y'$(which, as you know, is the slope a point $T$).

At this point you have everything needed finding the equation of a tangent line.

Comment: Yes, but if you insert x=6 andy=-1 in that outlet, you get denominator=0; what do you do then?

Comment: Exactly! It's mean that the tangent line is $x=6$.
Read here: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57310.html

Comment: Read inside that link.

Comment: I would probably just write that the slope on $T(6,-1)$ is not defined, therefore the tangent line is $x=6$.

Comment: I've read it (three times), but I don't understand it (I really tried to, though). My english isn't that advanced to understand all the mathematical terms :(  ...

Comment: just one more question, a word "slope" is used a lot in that link you posted and I don't know what it means (I've looked for it in online dictionary, but got no proper "solutions"/explanations. How would you define that word?

Comment: Try to answer to the following questions: 1. What is the slope of line $x=t$(where $t\in\mathbb{R}$)? 2. Slope is given by $m=(y_2 - y_1)/(x_2 - x_1)$, draw those points and look at the slope; suppose that $m$ is **not defined**, what is the geometrical interpretation of that?

Comment: ohhh now I know what you mean ...

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

We don't need to bother whether the point$(6,1)$ lies outside, on or inside the given ellipse.

Equation of any line passing through  $(6,1)$ can be written as $$\frac{y-1}{x-6}=m\ \ \ \  (1)$$ where $m$ is the gradient/slope

Find the intersection of $(1)$ with the  given curve by replacing $y$ with $mx-6m-1$ to form a Quadratic equation in $x$

Now for tangency the two intersection must coincide $\implies$ the discriminant of the Quadratic equation must be equal to zero

The nature of the two values of $m$  will actually determine the number of tangents

Observe:

If the point lies inside the ellipse, both the values $m$ will complex implying no real tangent

If the point lies on the ellipse, both the values $m$ will be same(real) implying exactly one real tangent

If the point lies outside the ellipse, both the values $m$ will be real & distinct implying two real real tangents

Comment: But how do you calculate equation of a tangent in (6,-1) with help of an outlet?

Comment: I get: y'= -12/0 (?!) and don't know how to get x=6 from that ...

Comment: @user111410, my method is without calculus

Comment: @user111410, have you formed the Quadratic equation in $x$?

Comment: How can you define word "slope/gradient"? I don't understand it :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11877/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-user111410)